# Getting particular value from Array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am getting response as array. I am manipulating that to get particular value from each array element.

Actual response:

[image]

When I do

```
 //carb_value is a array that contain the above response

  var l = this.carbs_value.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(this.carbs_value[i]);
  }
```

I am getting :

[image]

what i need is, select particular value from each element of an array like

```
0: { carbs: 30}
1: { carbs: 25}
```

Comment: What if you modify it like console.log(this.carbs_value[i].carbs); ? I don't know Angular but in vuejs you can have computed properties where you would transform the values the way you like. Here you can also iterate through the received array and add clean values (only the values you need) to a new array of objects and use that.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze That way he will only get the value of `carbs` printed. What he want is a key-value pair of `carbs` property.

Comment: @NickSurmanidze  I am getting undefined if I do like that

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are outputing the whole record. You can just go (prefer [forEach](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_foreach.htm) to manually iterating):

```
this.carbs_value.forEach(record => console.log({ carbs: record.carbs }));
```

If you'd like to save to a new array, you can use [map](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_map.htm):

```
const filtered = this.carbs_value.map(record => { carbs: record.carbs });
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: getting undefined warning

Comment: Then it means that your `this.carbs_value` does not have a correct value anymore, can you check it? This code shoud be fine, see no reason why it would fail otherwise.

Comment: You should now accept the correct answer to close your topic. This is good practice on Stack Overflow to avoid lurking open questions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const carbs_value = [
{ _id : "someval", quantity: 22, item: "val", carbs: 30},
{ _id : "someval", quantity: 22, item: "val", carbs: 3},
{ _id : "someval", quantity: 22, item: "val", carbs: 350},
{ _id : "someval", quantity: 22, item: "val", carbs: 630},
];

const allowed = ['carbs'];

const filtered = carbs_value.map(e=> Object.keys(e)
  .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = e[key];
    return obj;
  }, {})   );
  
  console.log(filtered);
  
  
console.log("So now you can select an element:");
  
   console.log(filtered[0]);
   console.log(filtered[1]);
```

Comment: i am getting empty array

Comment: When you hit Run Snippet above, you can see the code working correctly. If you need more specific help with your code, let me know more details and I will help